# Is it possible to conditionally specify the database in a fully qualified table name in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

At work we have three SQL Server 2008 R2 database environments: production, test and development.

In the production environment, different parts of our system run on 3 different database servers (let's call them `PROD1`, `PROD2` and `PROD3`), while in the development environment we have all the databases running on the same server (let's call it `DEV1`).

This is normally not a problem, since most of our SQL code doesn't need to refer to objects outside its own database. But in a handful of cases a view or a stored procedures need to refer to a table, view or function that not only reside in another database, but in a database on a different production server. I.e. we have a view on `PROD3` that need to look up a user in the user list on `PROD1` like this:

```
PROD1.UserDB.UserSchema.UserList
```

Of course this gives us problems in the test environment, because we need these views/stored procedures to refer to different servers, depending on where they run.

My question: is it possible to have conditional values in a fully qualified table name (`ServerName.DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName`) in T-SQL? I.e. could I have somethjing like this `(PROD1|DEV1).UserDB.UserSchema.UserList` in a view or stored procedure? Or maybe in some way get the server name from a variable, which we could then set depending on the current server?

Bonus question: in one case we even have to also change the database name. Can this be done in a similar manner?

I realize that we could get around this by creating a dynamic SQL statement in a string and then executing it. But for various reasons we would very much like to avoid this approach.

Comment: what about just conditionally changing the connection string?

Comment: maybe [linked servers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) might help you

Comment: @ArturUdod: Changing the connection string wouldn't work, since the problem is in a view or a stored procedure, which already reside on the database server, and so doesn't use a connection string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned, you do need to use the dynamic SQL. But you can use it for the object creation: simply to create the synonym in the dynamic SQL for all objects which need to be accessed from the another server and / or another database.

In this case all your code will be static and only during the installation / deployment process using the dynamic SQL the needed object will be referenced.

The code can be like the following:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

if @@servername = 'DEV1'
    set @sql = 'create synonym vUserList for [Dev1].UserDB.UserSchema.UserList'
else
    set @sql = 'create synonym vUserList for [PROD1].UserDB.UserSchema.UserList'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

And all your code (SPs, functions, etc.) can use this synonym - vUserList

In the same manner you can change the targeted database name depends on the environment - test, dev or prod

Comment: Do you mean 'not', i.e. "As already mentioned, you do **not** need to use the dynamic SQL."?

Comment: Thank you. This seems like the way to go. I will start implementing it on the development server. Unfortunately I need the approval of our Head DB Admin to implement it any where else, and he is (of course) on holiday right now. So the full implementation will have to wait.

Question about how to do things here: Should I have waited marking this as the accepted answer, until I had implemented it fully (and thereby knew that it worked)?

Answer (score 2):

For cross database references your best bet might be using [synonyms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187552.aspx). The definition of the synonyms will be different between DEV and PROD, but the definition of the complex objects (views, SPs etc) that use the synonyms can remain unchanged.

Comment: This helped me a lot. The only reason i chose @Sandr's answer as the most helpful was because of the code snippet, which also told me about @@servername. I would vote this answer up, but because I'm new to the site, I don't yet have the necessary reputation to do that. Sorry. But thank you for getting me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

You want a combination of [Linked Servers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190479.aspx) and [server aliases](http://alexpinsker.blogspot.co.uk/2007/08/how-to-give-alias-to-sql-linked-server.html).

Comment: I agree that Linked Servers could help me here, but since that would mean going through OLE DB, I'm worried about performance, especially compared with synonyms which were also suggested. So I will try the synonyms first, and if that doesn't work, I will try Linked Servers.

Comment: It's not a matter - in case of distributed server you will need the linked server...